# flowplayer - how to play video?

Tags: jquery, flowplayer

Here is the code which I tried using:

```
// configure rtmp for this demo
flowplayer.conf.rtmp = "rtmp://s3b78u0kbtx79q.cloudfront.net/cfx/st";
flowplayer.conf.ratio = 0.4167;
flowplayer(function (api, root) {

    // when a new video is about to be loaded
    api.bind("load", function () {

    // when a video is loaded and ready to play
    }).bind("ready", function () {
        $('video').trigger('click');
        var api = flowplayer();
    });

    api.load([{
        webm: "http://stream.flowplayer.org/bauhaus/624x260" + ".webm"
    },
    ]);
});
```

Demo: 

## FIDDLE

But I dont understand, and did not see such demo or example for such situation:

javascript selects video source, video is loaded and played. Different videos can be 50-150, I am not sure, so we dont load them all on the page.

And not page refresh.

As I understand api.load should play the video, but it does not, user needs to click with the mouse.

Tried triggering click event with jQuery, but that does not help.

**Update:**

Also when copying from jsfiddle, and running it all in my localhost server the javascript throws error:

Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'pick' of undefined flowplayer.js:232

```
load: function(video, callback) {

        if (api.error || api.loading || api.disabled) return;

        // resolve URL
        video = urlResolver.resolve(video);

        // engine.pick - library here throws error in my test page on local computer
        $.extend(video, engine.pick(video.sources));

        if (video.src) {
           var e = $.Event("load");
           root.trigger(e, [api, video, engine]);

           if (!e.isDefaultPrevented()) {
              engine.load(video);

              // callback
              if ($.isFunction(video)) callback = video;
              if (callback) root.one("ready", callback);
           } else {
              api.loading = false;
           }
        }

        return api;
     },
```

Comment: You forgot to attach your code snippet(s).

Comment: yeah, I am trying, fighting with code editor, which does not allow to post, complains about 4 spaces :D actually here is the code: http://jsfiddle.net/UHc8N/

Comment: Paste the code, mark the whole thing and select the **Code Sample** icon. Provide your [JsFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/UHc8N/) with your question too! :)

Comment: I see 'Code' icon. If this is the same what you are talking about, it still complains. I tried making all lines indented by 4 spaces but stil complains. I would like that they implement editor like sublime text here instead of this trash :(

Comment: when removed js fiddel link, then it stopped complaining. http://jsfiddle.net/UHc8N/